# How to add an element to HashMap<K, List<V>> using merge function

Tags: java, merge, hashmap

When maintaining a HashMap, merge is a very useful command. I like the concise way to add a number to a sum using expressions like
`map.merge(key, value, Double::sum);`

I have a HashMap<String, List> that I want to update. I could use something like

```
if (!map.containsKey(key)) map.put(key, new List());
map.get(key).add(value);
```

is there a more elegant way using merge to achieve this?

Comment: You should look for the `map.compute` sibling functions in docs.

Comment: What is your initial problem? Don't you need to group incoming data somehow? This may be achieved with stream/groupBy instead of the looping it

Answer (score 3):

The `merge` method can be similarly used here:

```
map.merge(key,
     List.of(value),
     (l1, l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(), Stream.of(value)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Note: I used `Stream` here because the list can be immutable (this is the case with the initial value `List.of(value)`)

Unless you're using a `ConcurrentHashMap`, however, I doubt this would be as elegant as the simple `if` solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of the data you need to build the Map up-front then you can do this

```
final Map<String, List<X>> result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.key, Collectors.toList()));
```

Otherwise, you could use computeIfAbsent, but it's basically the same as what you've already got

```
result.computeIfAbsent(x.key, (key) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(x);
```

Comment: `putIfAbsent(x.key, new ArrayList<>())` creates an empty list on every call, which is wasteful. You should use `computeIfAbsent()` instead.